# Changing EAPOL version on nmcli hotspot

Tags: raspberry-pi, networkmanager

I've setup a hotspot with nmcli on a Raspberry Pi running Buster by:

1. installing network-manager:

   `sudo apt-get install network-manager`
2. Setting up a hotspot profile:

   `sudo nmcli c add type wifi ifname wlan0 con-name hotspot ssid ssidname 802-11-wireless.mode ap ipv4.method shared 802-11-wireless.band bg 802-11-wireless.channel 11 wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk password`
3. Disabling dhcpcd (don't have that command handy)
4. Starting the hotspot.

   `sudo nmcli c up hotspot`

The problem is that the hotspot defaults to using eapol version 3 (802.1x-2010) which is not supported yet by some hardware that I'm trying to connect to the Pi's network so it will never finish the handshake.

Is there some configuration in NetworkManager or nmcli command I can use to define the eapol version to use? I searched through the nmcli 802-11 fields to no avail.

I know I can use hostapd + dnsmasq + bridge but this is (hopefully) simpler.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass the `eapol_version=1` option from **NetworkManager** to **wpa_supplicant** directly, but you can work around this limitation:

1. Edit your `wpa_supplicant.service`:

   ```
   systemctl edit --full wpa_supplicant.service
   ```

   and replace the line:

   ```
   ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
   ```

   with:

   ```
   ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
   ```

   where `wlan0` is the name of your wireless interface. If you don't provide the `-i` option switch, **wpa_supplicant** will not read your configuration file.
2. Create the configuration file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` with the desired option:

   ```
   eapol_version=1
   ```
3. Reload **SystemD** and restart the supplicant:

   ```
   systemctl daemon-reload
   systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service
   ```